Expected behaviour when expanding a template parameter pack into an inner template declaration
There are two scenarios:

You could use a template parameter pack and expand it into a nested template declaration of non-type template parameters:

template<class... Ts>
struct Outer {
    template<typename Ts::type...>
    void inner(){}
};  

I thought this would be pretty straight forward, since this is technically possible since C++11, but the resulting behavior differs greatly between compilers:
Calling the following member functions on the variable Outer<std::type_identity<bool>, std::type_identity<int>> outer{}; results in the following (Demo - comment in/out the specific lines in main to see the compiler outputs):
outer.inner<true, 42>();:

GCC: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
clang: compiles
MSVC: compiles

outer.inner<1.0, 2.0>();:

GCC: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
clang: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'Vals'
MSVC: Failed to specialize function template 'void Outer<std::type_identity<bool>, std::type_identity<int>>::inner(void)' (followed by an ICE)

outer.inner<true>();:

GCC: ICE
clang: candidate template ignored: deduced too few arguments for expanded pack 'Vals'; no argument for 2nd expanded parameter in deduced argument pack <true>
MSVC: compiles

outer.inner<>();:

GCC: compiles
clang: candidate template ignored: deduced too few arguments for expanded pack 'Vals'; no argument for 1st expanded parameter in deduced argument pack <>
MSVC: compiles

While clang behaves the way I would have personally expected, the discrepancy between compilers makes me think I'm doing something not officially allowed (maybe a clang extension?), so what is does the official standard say should happen here?

With C++20 concepts it is now syntactically valid(?) to expand a template parameter pack into a nested template argument list using constrained type parameters.

template<class, std::size_t>
concept At = true;

template<std::size_t... Is>
struct Outer{
    template<At<Is>... Ts>
    void inner(Ts...){}
};

Calling the following member functions on the variable Outer<0, 1> outer{}; results in the following (Demo - comment in/out the specific lines in main to see the compiler outputs):
outer.inner(0, 1);:

GCC: compiles
clang: compiles
MSVC: compiles

outer.inner(0, 1, 2);:

GCC: error: mismatched argument pack lengths while expanding 'At<Ts, Is>'
clang: candidate function [with Ts = <int, int>] not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
MSVC: the associated constraints are not satisfied

outer.inner(0);:

GCC: error: mismatched argument pack lengths while expanding 'At<Ts, Is>'
clang: candidate template ignored: deduced too few arguments for expanded pack 'Ts'; no argument for 2nd expanded parameter in deduced argument pack <int>
MSVC: the associated constraints are not satisfied

Here my guess would be that GCC and MSVC are correct, as they seem to behave the same way as with the rewritten from, in which case clang also behaves like GCC and MSVC (Demo):
template<std::size_t... Is>
struct Outer{
    template<class... Ts>
        requires (At<Ts, Is> && ...)
    void inner(Ts...){}
};

But clang seems to create some sort of fixed length parameter pack which enables some interesting scenarios, like leading packs (Demo):
template<std::size_t... Is>
struct Outer{
    template<At<Is>... Ts, class U>
    void inner(Ts..., U){}
};

int main() {
   Outer outer<0, 1>{}.inner(true, 1, 2.0);
}

Which compiles with clang and deduces Ts = <bool, int> and U = double.
So the question is once again, which behavior is correct according to the standard?

outer.inner<true, 42>() GCC: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1) - please post a [mre] in the question.

The examples are in the godbolt links. I just posted one link per section where you can comment in/out the specific line to see the results, so that it wouldn't result in too many links.

the first godbolt link has code different than the code here. The godbolt demo has to be modified to get the reported errors and the code posted here is incomplete. You better focus on one single example. Include the code and the complete error message. If asking one focused question doesnt answer your bigger questions sufficiently you can open another focused follow up question

Well the godbolt link includes some extra code for more informative output that would only distract from the main point of the question. And I think it is important to see all the examples together to get a clearer picture of compiler discrepancies. But the question did get pretty long, so I could split this into two questions, one for the nttp part and one for the constrained type parameter part.

comment in/out the specific lines in main to see the compiler outputs This should be done in the question as a [mre]. Don't make SO users to guess/edit your code for getting the desired errors.

Thank you for your suggestions on how to improve my question. I removed the extra diagnostic code from the links, as it may indeed be confusing. Unfortunately it's impossible to have a single example that produces all the different compiler errors (since the compiler will probably stop after the first error, definitely if it is an ICE), hence the admittedly unusual formatting. I'll leave the question like this for now and if it is indeed too big/confusing I'll remove it and maybe split it into multiple questions.

Better MCVE.

For the first example, the behaviour is perfectly well-specified by the standard. According to [temp.param]/2

[...] typename followed by a qualified-id denotes the type in a non-type parameter-declaration. [...]

That means typename Ts::type means a non-type template parameter whose type is Ts::type. It can't really be anything else: it can't be a type template parameter named Ts::type because you can't declare a template parameter to have a qualified name.
Then, [temp.param]/17 says

[...] A template parameter pack that is a parameter-declaration whose type contains one or more unexpanded packs is a pack expansion. [...]

One of the examples is
template <class... T>
  struct value_holder {
    template <T... Values> struct apply { };    // Values is a non-type template parameter pack
  };                                            // and a pack expansion

This makes it clear what is supposed to happen: the ... expands the pack T in the declaration of apply. For example, the class value_holder<bool, int> contains a nested class template apply that takes one bool and one int template argument.
In your example the template parameter pack of the member template inner is unnamed, but this difference is not relevant: typename Ts::type... is just a parameter-declaration with the optional name omitted.
Clang behaves correctly; I've no idea why the other compilers don't. Please file a bug against GCC.
In your second example Clang is also correct. Later in [temp.param]/17 we have this sentence:

A type parameter pack with a type-constraint that contains an unexpanded parameter pack is a pack expansion.

At<Is>... Ts is a type parameter pack whose type-constraint is At<Is>, so this declaration expands the pack Is, resulting in a fixed-length type template parameter list. Ts denotes this fixed-length list, and is then expanded by the parameter declaration Ts... into a function parameter list whose length equals that of Is.

Awesome, thank you. I suspected clang is correct for the first example, I was just surprised the other compilers couldn't handle it at all... I'll file a bug report for both GCC and MSVC. I'm a little surprised by the second example though. I've always thought the constrained parameter syntax and the requires syntax could be used interchangeably, but this means they can have distinct behaviors that are impossible to replicate in the respective other syntax.
